# Dynamic javascript redirection

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, redirect

I need to redirect users to a unique url when they visit a specific link which corresponds to a certain/row/column in the mysql database.

Here is what I mean:

The mysql database has a table table123 with a row id 123 and inside a column name "column123".
This row and column correspond to the webpage1.html

Normal javascript redirection is like this:

```
<script>location.replace('http://website.com/webpage2.html');</script>
```

What I need to do is extract the value from column123 of the webpage1.html and add it to the redirection url, so it would redirect specifically with that value.

For example:

```
<script>location.replace('http://website.com/webpage2.html/go/dbtable123row123column123value');</script>
```

This redirection script will be placed on top of the php page that will call the other php pages, so it has to be dynamic every time, thus the redirection script has to use dynamic placeholder, not static value, except the domain name.

Thanks

Comment: Use PHP to determine what url to redirect them to and then write it into your html page dynamically like: `<?php echo $redirect_url; ?>`

Comment: Why use javascript? `header('Location: http://website.com/webpage2.html/go/'.$table123row123column123);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table really is mysql table and the javascript has no way to access that information, follow other suggestions and deal with it on the server-side. If somehow, the table data are printed on the html document where you want the redirect to take place then you can consider the following. (Though, it would really make more sense to manage this server-side).

Assuming you have given unique id to your column and assuming that the table is on the web page that you have your location.replace call on.

```
location.replace("http://website.com/webpage2.html/go/" + $('#column123').text())
```

Without jQuery, you could use

```
document.getElementById('#column123').innerHTML (or text?)
```

If it is not practical to assign an id to the column, you can possibly use some [jQuery selector magic](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) with [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
location.replace("http://website.com/webpage2.html/go/" + $('#dbtable123 > tr:eq(1) > td:eq(3)').text())
```

(none tested)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't redirect in PHP for whatever reason, here's what I'd do.  Grab the proper web page from your database using AJAX.  I'd suggest using a library such as jQuery to help you do that.  If you use jQuery it'll look something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.get(
    '/script/that/queries/db.php',
    'your=query_string&goes=here',
    function(data) {
      if(data.url.length > 0) {
        location.href = data.url;
      }
    },
    'json'
  );
});
```

You didn't specify when you want this redirect to fire, so I just put it in the standard body onload.  Anyway, after you write that `$.get()` function call, then in your `/script/that/queries/db.php`, you'll want to perform your database query based on the get variable(s), and print a JSON encoded array with the valid page you want to redirect to:

```
$json = array('url' => '/webpage2.html');
print json_encode($json);
```

Of course I've just written some pseudo code, but hopefully it'll help get the idea across.  You'll want to make sure you validate/sanitize all info being querying the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply.Make dynamic url with php script.

```
header('Location: http://website.com/'.$table123row123column123);
```